# Finding inverse in this case?

Tags: linear-algebra

Define a linear transformation $T\colon \mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^3$, such that $T(x) = [x]_B$ ($B$-coordinate vector of $x$).

$B = \{b_1, b_2, b_3\}$, which is a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$.

$b_1 = (1, 1, 0)$ 
$b_2 = (0, 1, 1)$
$b_3 = (1, 1, 1)$

$T$ is a matrix transformation $T(x) = Ax$ for each $x$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Find $A$.

I think to solve this, I would first write out the equation

$x = [P]_B[x]_B$, the change of coordinate times the $B$ coordinate vector $x$ equals to $x$.

Taking the inverse of $[P]_B$ would yield $(P[B])^{-1}x = [x]_B$. This matches the form of

$T(x) = Ax$, since plugging in $T(x)$ yields $[x]_B = Ax$. So finding $(P[B])^{-1}$, which is the inverse of the basis $B$, would give me $A$.

Can someone verify if that's correct? I think I got $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0\\ -1 & 1 & 0\\ 1 & -1 & 1\end{bmatrix}$.

If not, can someone tell me how I should solve it?

Answer (score 1):

$T : V\rightarrow W$ is a linear transformation. So in $V=W={\bf R}^3$ we choose bases so that we can write $T$ into a matrix form $A$. As you said, in $V$ we have a canonical basis $E:=\{e_i\}$ and in $W$ we choose $B:=\{ b_i\}$. So in fact, $T(x)=[x]_B$ means $$ A[x]_E=[x]_B $$

For instance $$[e_1]_E=(1,0,0),\ [b_i]_E=b_i,\ [b_1]_B=(1,0,0)$$

That is $b_1$ is a fixed vector but the expression is different wrt chosen basis.

Now to find $A$, we must apply a suitable vectors. For calculation, we choose vectors in $B$ :

Note that $$  A[b_i]_E=[b_i]_B \Rightarrow A[b_1b_2b_3]= I $$

Hence $$ A = [b_1b_2b_3]^{-1} $$

Comment: Sorry, but I'm still confused. I don't understand how you would tie this in to finding A.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is not correct otherwise A operated over b1,b2,b3 must give e1,e2,e3(the standard basis).
What you can do is write e1,e2,e3 in linear combination of b1,b2,b3 and from that combination find out A.

Comment: oh, ok. Can you tell me how I should go about doing it then? I'm still confused.

Comment: Suppose (1,0,0)= a(1,1,0)+b(0,1,1)+c(1,1,1) then first column of A is (a,b,c). Similarly write (0,1,0) and (0,0,1) in such combination and find 2nd & 3rd column of A.